# TextInfo ToTitleCase missing in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, title-case

I am trying to convert a string to title case in my cross platform Xamarin app using the following code.

```
string rawString = "this is a test string";
System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
string formattedString = textInfo.ToTitleCase(rawString);
//Expected output is "This Is A Test String"
```

I cannot run this code as the compiler insists that there is no definition for ToTitleCase in TextInfo. However the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Globalization_TextInfo_ToTitleCase_System_String_) says otherwise.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the latest NuGet packages for everything (including all .Net packages and Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: Please include `using System.Globalization;`  and tell me if you notice any difference. You will also need to remove the prefix behind `TextInfo`

Comment: You're reading the documentation for full fat .Net Framework, Xamarin uses Mono which may not include all APIs.

Comment: @Greggz I have also tried that with the same error message resulting.

Comment: As @DavidG said, it's not available at the Mono framework. You can't do that in the shared code. Instead, you can use a dependency service, once `ToTitleCase` is available on the platform side.